How to exclude holidays of two different countries from date range count in SQL
I have a table looking like this:
deals



id
sub_id
deal_start
deal_end
country_A
country_B




10
1
2024-10-21
2024-10-25
USA
RUS


10
2
2024-10-21
2024-10-25
USA
CHN


10
3
2024-10-21
2024-10-24
RUS
USA


11
1
2024-10-21
2024-10-25
CHN
RUS


11
2
2024-10-21
2024-10-23
CHN
USA



I need to calculate the term of the deal for each row, but excluding weekends and holidays of each of two countries.
For this purpose, I have a table of weekends and holidays for all countries on all dates looking like this.
Holidays
1 - business day
2 - holiday or weekend



date
country
day_type




2024-10-21
RUS
2


2024-10-21
CHN
1


2024-10-21
USA
1


2024-10-22
RUS
1


2024-10-22
CHN
2


2024-10-22
USA
1


2024-10-23
RUS
1


2024-10-23
CHN
1


2024-10-23
USA
2


2024-10-24
RUS
2


2024-10-24
CHN
1


2024-10-24
USA
2



I'm using SQL Impala dialect and tried query like this, but without success. In addition, this approach does not take into account overlapping dates. Finally, I can't use UDFs at my work.
SELECT id,
       sub_id,
       deal_start,
       deal_end,
       country_A,
       country_B,
       DATEDIFF(d.deal_end, d.deal_start) AS dirty_term,
       COUNT(hA.date) AS country_A_hd,
       COUNT(hB.date) AS country_B_hd,
       (DATEDIFF(d.deal_end, d.deal_start) - GREATEST(COUNT(hA.date), COUNT(hA.date))
FROM deals AS d
LEFT JOIN holydays AS hA ON hA.country=d.country_A AND hA.date BETWEEN d.deal_start AND d.deal_end AND hA.day_type = 2
LEFT JOIN holydays AS hB ON hB.country=d.country_B AND hB.date BETWEEN d.deal_start AND d.deal_end AND hB.day_type = 2
GROUP BY id,
       sub_id,
       deal_start,
       deal_end,
       country_A,
       country_B

Ideally I need to get this result:



id
sub_id
deal_start
deal_end
country_A
country_B
datediff
total_AB_hd
real_term




10
1
2024-10-21
2024-10-25
USA
RUS
4
3
1


10
2
2024-10-21
2024-10-25
USA
CHN
4
3
1


10
3
2024-10-21
2024-10-24
RUS
USA
3
2
1


11
1
2024-10-21
2024-10-25
CHN
RUS
4
3
1


11
2
2024-10-21
2024-10-23
CHN
USA
2
1
1



Using following logic:



date
2024-10-21
2024-10-22
2024-10-23
2024-10-24
Total holidays




total_AB_hd (desired result)
2
2
1
2
3


country_A
1
2
1
2
2


country_B
2
1
1
2
2



Please help.
And big thanks for your time.

After some tinkering in my MySQL setup, I think I found a solution. Which hopefully you won't have much trouble porting over to your "SQL Impala dialect" setup.
SELECT id,
    sub_id,
    deal_start,
    deal_end,
    country_A,
    country_B,
    DATEDIFF(d.deal_end, d.deal_start) AS datediff,
    COUNT(hA.date) AS total_AB_hd,
    (DATEDIFF(d.deal_end, d.deal_start) - COUNT(hA.date)) AS real_term
FROM deals AS d
JOIN holidays AS hA ON 
    hA.country = d.country_A AND
    hA.date BETWEEN d.deal_start AND d.deal_end
JOIN holidays AS hB ON 
    hB.country = d.country_B AND 
    hB.date BETWEEN d.deal_start AND d.deal_end AND
    hA.date = hB.date
WHERE
    hA.day_type = 2 OR hB.day_type = 2
GROUP BY 
    id,
    sub_id;

+------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| id   | sub_id | deal_start | deal_end   | country_A | country_B | datediff | total_AB_hd | real_term |
+------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
|   10 |      1 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | USA       | RUS       |        4 |           3 |         1 |
|   10 |      2 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | USA       | CHN       |        4 |           3 |         1 |
|   10 |      3 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-24 | RUS       | USA       |        3 |           3 |         0 |
|   11 |      1 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | CHN       | RUS       |        4 |           3 |         1 |
|   11 |      2 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-23 | CHN       | USA       |        2 |           2 |         0 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------+

First, the deals table is joined twice with the holiday table on date and country.
SELECT *
FROM deals AS d
JOIN holidays AS hA ON 
    hA.country = d.country_A AND
    hA.date BETWEEN d.deal_start AND d.deal_end
JOIN holidays AS hB ON 
    hB.country = d.country_B AND 
    hB.date BETWEEN d.deal_start AND d.deal_end AND
    hA.date = hB.date
ORDER BY id ASC, sub_id ASC, hA.date ASC; -- sorting to make the table look pretty

This results in a table where every deal is matched with the corresponding holidays in the two countries in that time period.
+------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+---------+----------+
| id   | sub_id | deal_start | deal_end   | country_A | country_B | date       | country | day_type | date       | country | day_type |
+------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+---------+----------+
|   10 |      1 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | USA       | RUS       | 2024-10-21 | USA     |        1 | 2024-10-21 | RUS     |        2 |
|   10 |      1 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | USA       | RUS       | 2024-10-22 | USA     |        1 | 2024-10-22 | RUS     |        1 |
|   10 |      1 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | USA       | RUS       | 2024-10-23 | USA     |        2 | 2024-10-23 | RUS     |        1 |
|   10 |      1 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | USA       | RUS       | 2024-10-24 | USA     |        2 | 2024-10-24 | RUS     |        2 |
|   10 |      2 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | USA       | CHN       | 2024-10-21 | USA     |        1 | 2024-10-21 | CHN     |        1 |
|   10 |      2 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | USA       | CHN       | 2024-10-22 | USA     |        1 | 2024-10-22 | CHN     |        2 |
|   10 |      2 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | USA       | CHN       | 2024-10-23 | USA     |        2 | 2024-10-23 | CHN     |        1 |
|   10 |      2 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | USA       | CHN       | 2024-10-24 | USA     |        2 | 2024-10-24 | CHN     |        1 |
|   10 |      3 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-24 | RUS       | USA       | 2024-10-21 | RUS     |        2 | 2024-10-21 | USA     |        1 |
|   10 |      3 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-24 | RUS       | USA       | 2024-10-22 | RUS     |        1 | 2024-10-22 | USA     |        1 |
|   10 |      3 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-24 | RUS       | USA       | 2024-10-23 | RUS     |        1 | 2024-10-23 | USA     |        2 |
|   10 |      3 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-24 | RUS       | USA       | 2024-10-24 | RUS     |        2 | 2024-10-24 | USA     |        2 |
|   11 |      1 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | CHN       | RUS       | 2024-10-21 | CHN     |        1 | 2024-10-21 | RUS     |        2 |
|   11 |      1 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | CHN       | RUS       | 2024-10-22 | CHN     |        2 | 2024-10-22 | RUS     |        1 |
|   11 |      1 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | CHN       | RUS       | 2024-10-23 | CHN     |        1 | 2024-10-23 | RUS     |        1 |
|   11 |      1 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-25 | CHN       | RUS       | 2024-10-24 | CHN     |        1 | 2024-10-24 | RUS     |        2 |
|   11 |      2 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-23 | CHN       | USA       | 2024-10-21 | CHN     |        1 | 2024-10-21 | USA     |        1 |
|   11 |      2 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-23 | CHN       | USA       | 2024-10-22 | CHN     |        2 | 2024-10-22 | USA     |        1 |
|   11 |      2 | 2024-10-21 | 2024-10-23 | CHN       | USA       | 2024-10-23 | CHN     |        1 | 2024-10-23 | USA     |        2 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+---------+----------+

Now all that is left to do, is to filter for all the rows, that have a holiday in either of the countries (WHERE hA.day_type = 2 OR hB.day_type = 2), to group by the deals identifier (GROUP BY id, sub_id) and you can count the total_AB_hd by using e.g. COUNT(hA.date) to count the dates that got grouped for each deal.

If you're going to hack around with variables within a mysql query, you should at least explain why, how they're used, and their relative merits.

@MatBailie thanks, for pushing me to do better. You were right to call my first answer hacky. I like the new one, I got now a lot better :)

It is unclear what you want/need to do with the columns datediff and total_AB_hd, so I  left them out...
WITH 
same_daytype_both AS (
  SELECT 
     b1.date, 
     b1.country country_A , 
     b2.country country_B ,
     b1.day_type
  FROM holidays b1
  INNER JOIN holidays b2 on b1.date = b2.date 
                  and b1.country <> b2.country
                  and b1.day_type = b2.day_type
)
SELECT 
  date,
  day_type,
  country_A,
  country_B,
  count(1) over (partition by day_type,country_A,country_B) as term
FROM same_daytype_both
WHERE country_A > country_B
ORDER BY date, country_A, country_B;

output:



date
day_type
country_A
country_B
term




2024-10-21
1
USA
CHN
1


2024-10-22
1
USA
RUS
1


2024-10-23
1
RUS
CHN
1


2024-10-24
2
USA
RUS
1



Meaning that only USA and RUS have a common holiday or weekend on October 24th (with your data).
see: DBFIDDLE
Because impala does not seem to support WITH (see: *), you might need to create a VIEW, so you can use that in the final SQL statement.
